# Script de verificação banco de dados tempo real

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Queria fazer um `script`, em que na página aparecesse:

"Loading.", "Loading.." "Loading...". Os 3 loadings mudariam constantemente e quando fosse inserir um resultado no `banco de dados` o loading desapareceria e apareceria o valor inserido no `banco de dados`.

Como faria tal coisa com `javascript` em tempo real e `php` para consulta de dados do `mysql`?

Obrigado

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Já tentei fazer o sistema, porém não sei faz o tempo real, peço desculpa mas sou novato.

Comment: @Gonçalo poste o código que já tentou, é mais fácil para alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Ainda não tentei a parte do obter dados pois não manjo ajax.

Comment: Alguem pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Inciei um timer em Javascript com a cada tantos segundos mudar o texto exemplo:

```
<script>
var cont=0;

function nexload(){
cont++;
cont%=3;
var pontos='';
for(var i=0;i<cont;i++)
     pontos+='.';
document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = 'Carregando'+pontos;
}

new Timer(1000,function(){nextvalue();}).start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) e enquanto a requisição é feita, você pode exibir uma mensagem na tela para o usuário.

Comment: Boa tarde, pode me dar exemplo de código?